# CKEditor inline instance fails to reload after it's destroyed

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, inline

For the app I'm working on, users can edit text inline using CKEditor.  Recently, I've included 2 extra plugins that I modified: stylescombo and bidi.  For both of these, I just gave it a new name and modified what happens when text is clicked.

When a user clicks on a block of text to edit, I would dynamically load CKEditor onto it like this:

```
HTML: <div id="text-content">sample text</div>

JS: var $text = $("#text-content");
    $text.attr("contenteditable", true);
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    ...
    // toolbarOptions is an array of toolbar options
    var editor = CKEDITOR.inline("text-content", {toolbar: toolbarOptions});
```

When user clicks away from the CKEditor, I would destroy the editor like this:

```
editor.destroy(true);
editor = null;
$("#text-content").removeAttr("contenteditable");
```

Now all of this works fine the first time, but when I attempt to edit the text-content again, the CKEditor fails to load without any error whatsoever.  I console log the "editor" variable and I see the status of the editor being "unloaded".  After some debugging, I found that if I don't load one of the 2 customized plugins above, the editor can reload after being destroyed.  Any ideas why those 2 plugins are affecting the reloading of the inline CKEditor?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/22A6F/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with this? Your code looks good and similar worked for me locally.

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle can load ckeditor and custom plugins, right?  So you can get it working after customizing those 2 plugins I modified?

Comment: You can load [CKEditor from CDN](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/) and your plugins using [addExternal](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal). Or you can actually copy them to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Ok, added a demo.  See link above.

Comment: Your plugins apparently have a bug - they don't contain language files. There are 404 errors on console logged. If you fix them, everything will work.

Comment: Thanks!  I removed the "lang" property for both plugins and things work properly now.